# PTO (Hourly employee) and starting a new job

Tags: salary, new-job, hourly

On January 7th, 2019, I am starting a new job. However, before this happened, I had already booked time off from December 21st, 2018 until January 4th, 2019. The company I work for does not have a notice period, so I can basically tell them the same day that I am leaving.

Is there any way, I could still get paid for the Paid time off ([PTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paid_time_off)) that has already been approved and then start my new job on January 7th, 2019? Pay day will be on December 28th, 2018 and then two weeks after that again.

Comment: Where are you? Some jurisdictions require things like PTO be paid out, regardless of the circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way, I could still get paid for the PTO (Paid Time Off)
>   that has already been approved and then start my new job on January
>   7th, 2019?

Yes. You can give your notice on January 4th. That is the most sure way of getting paid for all of your PTO days.

Other than that, you'll have to consult the specifics of your HR's PTO Policies to find out.

It will likely depend on if all the days off have been accrued in the prior year, or if you are borrowing days off from the upcoming year.

Answer (score 2):

At least in the U.S., employers are generally required to pay out your accrued vacation/PTO time when you leave their employ. As long as it doesn't create a problem for them, they probably don't mind getting that off their books before you leave vs. after. Thus, if you provide enough notice to make up for the time you take off, it probably won't be a problem. At least that has been my experience, as there have been a couple times in which I've taken vacation time/PTO after I'd let it be known I was leaving:

- On one occasion I took a few days off (sandwiching a holiday weekend) to visit with a family member before they were to be deployed on military duty.
- Recently I changed jobs and took two days of PTO to accompany my child on an overnight school trip.

In both circumstances my expected (although not required) notice period was two weeks. Both times I submitted my resignation with extra time built in to more than make up for the time I would be missing: on the first occasion I provided three weeks notice and only took 3 vacation days; a rookie manager tried to say vacation wasn't allowed during notice period, but upper management approved the plan, since I was still working more than two weeks. On the second occasion I provided about 3 and 1/2 weeks notice and no one made any objection.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: That's what I was thinking, but didn't say explicitly. Thanks for pointing it out. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your contract, but normally if you already had the PTO approved you should be able to take it and get paid for it even if you resign immediately afterwards.

Comment: Lots of people in the US don't have formal contracts.  I've never had one.  For people in the US, it might be good to look at the HR manual.